# Find jQueryUI dialog size before opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I find the height of a jQueryUI dialog before it is opened?

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/kamLrn7v/, click "Size", then click "Open", and then click "Size" again.

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="size">Size</button>

$("#open").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 340,
    width: 430
});
$("#size").click(function () {
    console.log($("#dialog").height());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the dialog options:

```
$("#size").click(function () {
    var options = $("#dialog").dialog("option");
    console.log(options.height);
    console.log(options.width);
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bajLxw3/)

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that `$("#dialog").dialog("option").height` gives the outer height of the dialog (340 px), while `$("#dialog").height())` gives the available height inside the dialog (272 px).  See https://jsfiddle.net/4bajLxw3/1/.  My application to add a `div` with autoscroll inside the dialog, and must make it less than `272 px`.

Comment: you can show the dialog if its not open, get the height and then close it

Comment: Yea, was thinking of that.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Or maybe better yea, use the `open` event and size then get the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dialog `height` settings like this:

```
var diaHeight = $("#dialog").dialog("option", "height");
```

Using css and an additional `div` tag, you can set the `ui-dialog` scrolling behavior without having to know the dialog's height beforehand.  You'll need to load content into the nested element, however (if you are taking that route).

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bajLxw3/16/)

Comment: Thanks wahwahwah,  I wasn't clear.  The scrolling is for an autopopulate widget inside the dialog.